# Show Hyperlink Field only for Not NULL values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am pulling out data from certain database and displaying it on a table and the data displayed will be in hyperlink form. But there is one problem where the data shown is including null value.
my code is :

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NCR" ItemStyle-Width="150px" >
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text = '<%#Eval("form")%>' NavigateUrl = '<%# Eval("form","~/sapphire/nca" + Mid(Eval("form"), 4, 1) + ".aspx?form={0}") %>' />
```

let`s say i have 5 rows of data fetched (null,hey,yoyo,null,null)
the output should be like in table form under NCR :

```
     -,*hey*,-,*yoyo*,-,-
```

where hey and yoyo are clickable link.
please help ><

Comment: check this link http://forums.asp.net/t/959419.aspx?how+to+handle+null+values+for+Templatefield+hyperlink+etc+

Comment: @sharad i`ve tried the IIF method but it gave me this error"Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments"

Answer (score 0):

Try using ternary operator for checking null values

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text = '<%#Eval("form")%>' NavigateUrl = '<%# Eval("form")==null? "" : String.Format("{0}{1}{2}","~/sapphire/nca", Mid(Eval("form"), 4, 1),".aspx?form={0}" ) %>' />
```